# MEAN Stack protect layouts routes

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm Working with MEAN Stack , And i have 3 layouts and i want to protect every layout routes to prevent other layouts to access it

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: 'main-admin',
    component: MainAdminLayoutComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
                import('./layouts/main-admin-layout/main-admin-layout.module').then(m => m.MainAdminLayoutModule)
        }
    ]
},
{
    path: 'main-admin',
    component: MainAdminLayoutComponent,
    loadChildren: () =>
        import('./main-admin-components/main-admin.component.module').then(m => m.MainAdminComponentModule)
},
{
    path: '',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () => 
                import('./layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.module').then(m => m.AdminLayoutModule)
        }
    ]
},
{
    path: '',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    loadChildren: () =>
        import('./components/component.module').then(m => m.ComponentModule)
},
{
    path: 'user',
    component: SiteLayoutComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
                import('./layouts/site-layout/site-layout.module').then(m => m.SiteLayoutModule)
        }
    ]
},
{
    path: '',
    component: UserLayoutComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'account',
            loadChildren: () =>
                import('./layouts/user-layout/user-layout.module').then(m => m.UserLayoutModule)
        }
    ]
},
{
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundComponent
}
```

];

---

Each route i want to protect ... Let's say i just a user and if i want to access admin routes redirect me to my dashboard

Any help please ??!!

Answer (score 1):

The thing that you are trying to achieve over here is, users will have access to visit only particular components. In case if they are trying to visit a component for which they are not having access, they must be redirected to some other component.

This can be achieved by a feature called **Angular Route Resolvers**;. Usiing which you will run a piece of code before navigating ot that component and decide whether it can be navigated or not. You can find a detail implementation of route resolvers with example over here - https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-angular-route-resolvers-by-example

Comment: Is there any way to pass a condition to the route
For Example
`{
        path: 'product/create',
        data: { title: ' Create | Edit Product' },
        component: CreateProductComponent,
        // condition: localStorage.getItem('role') === 'admin'
},`
-----------------------------
it just what i want to do .... if there is something like that tell me !!